# How to get text other than the text which is specified using text attribute for a button (when it is clicked) in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, button, android-xml

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button10"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Reset"
 android:onClick="onReset"               
/>
```

onReset Function

```
public void onReset(View v){
        // by using getText(), we get whatever that is specified in android:text attribute in xml
    }
```

Can I get some other text other than "Reset" when this button is clicked. If yes, can you explain how?

Comment: If you dynamically `setText()` on button than you will get new text (which you set dynamically) when you will call `getText()`.

Comment: What you mean by other text ? you want to change button text and get that or you need to get other widget text or something else ?

Comment: be specific about the issue you are facing. currently the question is unclear. need more info

Answer (score 1):

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button.setText("NEW VALUE");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement..what kind of text you wants and from where.

You can get text from resources or from any string or from any view that is declared inside your class. It totally depends on your requirements. Please be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Your click listener is basically a simple method that is called when the button is clicked. There's nothing more special in this method..it will call when you press the button and will give you the view that is clicked in the params. So its your choice what you want to perform in your click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Change text of button (or other view from where u want to get text) dynamically before you want to get particular text.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, It is possible** by using tag.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="HiddenText"
        android:text="Welcome" />
```

Here visible text is `Welcome` but you can get `HiddenText` by using `getTag()`

**For Example :**

```
TextView txtView = findViewById(R.id.txt);
Toast.makeText(this, txtView.getTag()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```